# Uniqueness in law associated to nonlinear SDEs

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I do not understand the following when reading a paper on Propagation of Chaos, written by A.S.Sznitman:

> Consider an $n$- dimensional process $X$ satisfying the following SDE:
>   $$ dX_t = b(t, X_t, \mathbb{P}_t) \,dt + \sigma (t, X_t , \mathbb{P}_t) \,dW_t, \quad \quad \mathbb{P}_t = \text{Law} \, (X_t), \quad X_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n,$$
>   where $W$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion, $b^i (t ,x, \mathbb{P}_t)= \int b^i (t,x,y) \mathbb{P}_t (dy)$ and ${\sigma}^i_j (t ,x, \mathbb{P}_t)= \int {\sigma}^i_j (t,x,y) \mathbb{P}_t (dy)$.
>
> Suppose that $X=(X_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ satisfies the above SDE. If for some measure $\mathbb{Q}$ on $C([0,T], \mathbb{R}^n)$, the following SDE (interpreted similarly as above) is satisfied:
>   $$ dX_t = b(t, X_t , \mathbb{Q}_t) \,dt + \sigma ( t, X_t , \mathbb{Q}_t ) \,dW_t,$$ then the paper claims that $\mathbb{Q}= \text{Law} (X_t: 0 \leq t \leq T)$.

I have no idea how to show this rigorously. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hi this kinds of SDE are called McKean-Vlasov SDE, you can have a look [here](http://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/ywip2014/Talks/Santiago.pdf) and [there](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.1215v1.pdf) and to the references therein.

Best regards.